# Xamarin - How to pass object to event handler

Tags: c#, xamarin

**Disclaimer** - I am in need of a bit of guidance as I am **very** new to C# and Xamarin. Examples are greatly appreciated.

Basically I have an object named "newuserdata" in Page1 that I am passing to Page2.

Page1 - RegistrationUserPage.xaml.cs

```
...
    else
                    {

                        Userdata newuserdata = new Userdata();
                        newuserdata.firstname   = firstname;
                        newuserdata.lastname    = lastname;
                        newuserdata.birthday    = birthday;
                        newuserdata.phone       = phone;
                        newuserdata.password    = password;

                        var RegistrationUserBillingPage = new RegistrationUserBillingPage(newuserdata);
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(RegistrationUserBillingPage);
```

Page2 - RegistrationUserBillingPage.xaml.cs

```
...
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class RegistrationUserBillingPage : ContentPage
        {
            public Userdata newuserdata;

        public RegistrationUserBillingPage(Userdata newuserdata)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.newuserdata = newuserdata;

            // this works fine and I get the data
            first.Text = newuserdata.firstname;
        }

        async void SubmitButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //How do I get the object to this event so that I could get or set the values?

            // I would like to get the value
            /*
            second.Text = newuserdata.lastname;
            */

            // .. and I would like to set the value
            /*
            newuserdata.city = CityEntry.Text;
            */
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is - how do I access the object in my 'SubmbitButton_Clicked' method?

Comment: Did you try `this.newuserdata.lastname` ?

Comment: *facepalming myself* - I just figured that I was not firing the event. Thank you for your comment

Comment: No problem. If you think the Q&A is of value to another user, then you should answer and self-accept when allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did you try this.newuserdata.lastname ? – A Friend

I was not firing the event properly. Thank you @A Friend!